# Does the ScheduledTaskAgent and PeriodicTask need to be in a seperate assembly from the main app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I tried to follow this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) from Microsoft, best I can tell I did everything except putting the ScheduledTaskAgent and PeriodicTask in a seperate assembly.  When I run my app in the emulator and try to launch the Periodic task using:
**ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(_task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));**
Nothing happens, no exceptions and after a minute the ScheduledTaskAgent never starts and when I look under "Settings > Background Tasks" on the emulator nothing is listed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they need to be in a separate assembly, and you need to reference it in your `WMAppManifest.xaml`, like this:

```
<Tasks>
    <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="Views/MainPage.xaml" />
    <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
        <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="DMI.ScheduledAgent" Source="DMI.TaskAgent" Type="DMI.TaskAgent.ScheduledAgent" />
    </ExtendedTask>
```

You can read on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx) what the correct values for the `BackgroundServiceAgent` attributes are.

If you use the Visual Studio **Windows Phone Scheduled task Agent** template, the `BackgroundServiceAgent` task is automatically added in the `WMAppManifest.xaml` with the correct values.

Comment: So I split it out into a seperate assembly and I see it listed in "Settings > Background Tasks"  but nothing is still happening.  Do I need to do anything special to debug the ScheuledTaskAgent ?

Comment: 1 minute is a insanely long period. Try set it to 0. And nope, nothing special, should just work. Try use a Toast to see if it's actually running the ShellTask at all!

Comment: Thanks Claus,  I had the wrong class name in the Manifest, its working now.

Comment: Visual Studio didn't add the reference for me automatically. This was the final detail that made it work... Right click on your App's project and hit Add Reference, and then select your background agent project to add it as a reference. This will also add the correct xml statement for you.